# Javascript class name doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I want to get get class name by hovering mouse on it. All i get now on hover is **Class name: [objectHTMLCollection]**.
I'm using this code in html: onmouseover="class(this)"

```
function class() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
x[0].innerHTML = "Class name" + x + " ";
}
```

Comment: That's because `getElementsByClassName` selects a *collection*, not an *element*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone: To be fair, half the code above handles that correctly. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, it's not too bad. :) innerHTML is correctly addressed.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using this code in html: onmouseover="class(this)"

In that case, you should declare a parameter to your function and use it. An element's current set of class name(s) is available from its `className` property:

```
function showClass(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "Class name " + element.className;
}
```

Also note that I changed the name of the function. `class` is a keyword in JavaScript, you can't use it as an identifier. (You'll need to update your `onmouseover` accodingly.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any of [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Jav) in your code to name functions, variables etc.

You get `[objectHTMLCollection]` as a result of `toString()` method that gets implicitly called when you are trying to cast `x` (which is object) to a string by doing `"Class name" + x + " ";`. Use `x[0].className` instead.

Comment: `x.className` in the code in the question will be `undefined.`

Comment: Indeed, I missed that he is fetching a collection.